# TLocalizedComboBox does not call OnDrawItem

Tags: custom-controls, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to implement a custom control based on the TComboBox class. The code below does compile but the OnDrawItem (MyDrawItem) is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```
unit TLocalizedComboBox_unit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Types;

type
  TLocalizedComboBox = class(TComboBox)
  private
    { Private declarations }

  protected
    { Protected declarations }

  published
    { Published declarations }

  public
    { Public declarations }
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     procedure MyDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
end;

procedure Register;

implementation
constructor TLocalizedComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
     Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
     OnDrawItem := Self.MyDrawItem;

     inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

procedure TLocalizedComboBox.MyDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
   Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Items.Names[Index]);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyProjectsComponents', [TLocalizedComboBox]);

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved most of this in the code below. There is still a few things that are not the way I would like it to be.

- The code'inherited Style := csOwnerDrawFixed' only works when no different style is set in the designer. I have to set that property to csOwnerDrawFixed in the Designer or leave at the default 'csDropDown'. (b.t.w. that was why the DrawItem method was never called).
- The color differs from the csDropDownList ComboBoxes as you can see in the image below. The third one is my implementation from the code below.

[image]

```
unit TLocalizedComboBox_unit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Types, Vcl.Forms,
  TLanguagesManager_6, _LanguageManagerConstants;

type
  TLocalizedComboBox = class(TComboBox)
  private
    function GetForm(control: TControl) : TForm;

  published
     procedure DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect;  State: TOwnerDrawState); override;

  public
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

end;

procedure Register;

implementation
constructor TLocalizedComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
     inherited;

     inherited Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
end;

// Custom draw routine for the item. The displayed text is translated
procedure TLocalizedComboBox.DrawItem(Index: Integer; Rect: TRect;  State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
   itemToDisplay: string;
   translation  : string;
   form         : TForm;
   formName     : string;
begin
   itemToDisplay := Items[Index];
   translation   := itemToDisplay;

   if Length(itemToDisplay) > 0 then
   begin
      form          := GetForm(Self);

      if form <> nil then formName := form.Name + '.' else formName := '';
      
      translation := TLanguagesManager.GetSingleton.GetText(formName + Name + '.' + itemToDisplay, itemToDisplay);
   end;
   
   Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top, translation);
end;

// Find the Form this control is on
function TLocalizedComboBox.GetForm(control: TControl) : TForm;
var
   form: TControl;
begin
     form := control.Parent;

     while form <> nil do
     begin
          if form is TForm then
          begin
              Result := form as TForm;
              form := nil;
          end
          else
              form := form.Parent;
     end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyProjectsComponents', [TLocalizedComboBox]);

end;

end.
```

Comment: The colors are the default for cDropDownList (the first two) and cOwnerDrawFixed and baked into the standard TComboBox Control. Can I change that behavior?